# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: python, tensorflow

I an not sure about what's happening. Is it a bug or i am messed up. I am not sure why Session.run is throwing such exception. Is it because lack of arguments or invalid argument? Or the problem is somewhere else? Also, why it is saying caused by op placeholder X. X has no role in this test set. Placeholders are

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, image_height, image_width, NUM_CHANNELS])

Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])

X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, image_height, image_width, NUM_CHANNELS])

Y1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])
```

I am calling

```
train_cnn(X, X1)
```

My Code is :

```
def train_cnn(X, X1):
Y_prediction = my_conv_net(X)
Y1_prediction = my_conv_net(X1)
#    print(Y_prediction)
#    print(Y1_prediction)
Y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(Y_prediction)
Y1_pred = tf.nn.softmax(Y1_prediction)
#   Y_prediction_class = tf.argmax(Y_prediction, dimension=1)
#    print(Y_pred)
#    print(Y1_pred)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Y_prediction, labels=Y))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
#   hm_epochs = 8
f2 = open(r'D:\Speech_Project\oplog\accuracy_log.txt', 'a+')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    train_loss = []
    train_acc = []
    test_acc = []
    for i in range(num_itr):
    #   print(i)
    #   training results
        rand_index = np.random.choice(len(features), size=BATCH_SIZE)
        rand_x = features[rand_index]
        rand_x = np.expand_dims(rand_x, 3)
        rand_y = labels[rand_index]
        train_dict = {X: rand_x, Y: rand_y}
    #    f2.write("\n Train Dictionary: " + str(train_dict) +"\n\n")
    #    print(train_dict)
        sess.run(optimiser, feed_dict=train_dict)
    #    print(Y_pred)
    #    print(train_dict)
        temp_train_loss, temp_train_preds = sess.run([cost,Y_pred], feed_dict=train_dict)
    #    print(temp_train_preds)
    #    print(rand_y)
        temp_train_acc = get_accuracy(temp_train_preds, rand_y)
        print('Iteration: ' + str(i+1))
        if(i+1) % eval_every == 0:
            # testing results
            print('Iteration1: ' + str(i+1))
            test_index = np.random.choice(len(test_features), size=BATCH_SIZE_1)
            test_x = test_features[test_index]
            test_x = np.expand_dims(test_x, 3)
            test_y = test_labels[test_index]
        #    print(test_x)
        #    print(test_y)
            eval_dict = {X1: test_x, Y1: test_y}
        #    print(eval_dict)
        #    f2.write("\n Test Dictionary: " + str(eval_dict) + "\n\n")
        #    print(Y1_pred)
        #    print(eval_dict)
            temp_test_preds = sess.run(Y1_pred, feed_dict=eval_dict)
            print('Iteration2: ' + str(i+1))
            temp_test_acc = get_accuracy(temp_test_preds, test_y)
            # record and print results
            train_loss.append(temp_train_loss)
            train_acc.append(temp_train_acc)
            test_acc.append(temp_test_acc)
            acc_and_loss = [(i+1), temp_train_loss, temp_train_acc, temp_test_acc]
        #    acc_and_loss = [(i + 1), temp_train_loss, temp_train_acc]
            acc_and_loss = [np.round(x,2) for x in acc_and_loss]
        #    print('Iteration # {}. Train Loss: {:.2f}. Train Accuracy: {:.2f}.'.format(*acc_and_loss))
            print('Iteration # {}. Train Loss: {:.2f}. Train Accuracy: {:.2f}. Test Accuracy: {:.2f}.'.format(*acc_and_loss))
            f2.write("Iteration Number :\n" + str(i+1) + "\n\n")
            f2.write("Training Predictions :\n" + str(temp_train_preds) + "\n\n")
            f2.write("Training Labels are :\n" + str(rand_y) + "\n\n")
            f2.write("Testing Predictions :\n" + str(temp_test_preds) + "\n\n")
            f2.write("Testing Labels are :\n" + str(test_y) + "\n\n")
            f2.write("Iteration # " + str(i+1) + ", Train loss: " + str(temp_train_loss) + ", Train Accuracy: " + str(temp_train_acc) + ", Test Accuracy: " + str(temp_test_acc) + "\n\n")
        #    f2.write("Iteration # " + str(i + 1) + ", Train loss: " + str(temp_train_loss) + ", Train Accuracy: " + str(temp_train_acc) + "\n\n")
    save_path = saver.save(sess, 'D:\Speech_Project\my_model\my_model_01')
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
    f2.write("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
f2.close()
```

I am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/BanglaCNN01/banglacnn02.py", line 289, in <module>
train_cnn(X, X1)
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/BanglaCNN01/banglacnn02.py", line 218, in train_cnn
temp_test_preds = sess.run(Y1_pred, feed_dict=eval_dict)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/BanglaCNN01/banglacnn02.py", line 285, in <module>
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, image_height, image_width, NUM_CHANNELS])
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1502, in placeholder
name=name)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2149, in _placeholder
name=name)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
 [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Need insights on why this error/exception is occurring and how to resolve it.

Code for my_conv_net() :

```
def my_conv_net(input_data):
#   first convolutional layer, weights, biases, non linearity, pooling included
w_conv1 = weight_variable([4, 4, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(X, w_conv1) + b_conv1)
#   print(h_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
#   print(h_pool1)
#   first fc layer
w_fc1 = weight_variable([13*13*32, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool1_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool1, [-1, 13*13*32])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool1_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)
#   for dropout
#   h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
#   final output layer
w_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 4])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([4])
final_model_output = tf.matmul(h_fc1, w_fc2) + b_fc2
#   print(final_model_output)
#   final_model_output_sm = tf.nn.softmax(final_model_output)
#   print(final_model_output_sm)
return final_model_output
```

Comment: Can you share the code to `my_conv_net()`? It's not clear why fetching `Y1_pred` would depend on placeholder `X`, but it's possible that something in that function is capturing a reference to the placeholder. (One way to test whether this is happening would be to reverse the two calls to `my_conv_net()` so that you call `Y1_prediction = my_conv_net(X1); Y_prediction = my_conv_next(X)`.

Comment: Since you insist mrry, i have uploaded the code for my_conv_net(). It is the weights. biases and convolutional model. Also, one very interesting thing is that if i comment out the codes for temp_test_preds, i.e., all the testing part codes, training runs just fine.

Comment: A big thank you to mrry for pointing me to right direction.
Finally, i found what was wrong. In
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(X, w_conv1) + b_conv1), 
X should have been input_data.